# Sqlite Insert or Replace query with increment of an integer field

Tags: android, sqlite

There are three fields(_id,name,count) in in a table name poet. I want to check if poet name exist in the table then update count field with increment of 1 or else insert a new record with the given name and count as 1. Here is my query. It is inserting null value for count if there name not found in the table. Although it is working good if I want to update already existing records.

```
insert or replace into poet (_id,Name, count) values (
   (select _id from poet where Name = "SearchName"),
   "SearchName",
    (select count from poet where Name = "SearchName")+ 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about changing the query to use [ifnull](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) or [coalesce](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce).

```
insert or replace into poet (_id,Name, count) values (
   (select _id from poet where Name = "SearchName"),
   "SearchName",
    ifnull((select count from poet where Name = "SearchName"), 0) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to be clever.
Just use two commands:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    db.execSQL("UPDATE poet SET count = count + 1 WHERE Name = ?",
               new Object[]{ searchName });
    if (DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT changes()", null) == 0) {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO poet(Name, count) VALUES(?,?)",
                    new Object[]{ searchName, 1 });
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```